# Google CalDav Api wont return single instances of recurring events

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, caldav, sabredav

I am trying to get single instances of Recurring events from Google CalDav Api. I am using the following report request to get single instances

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<c:calendar-query xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:c="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"> 
    <d:prop> 
        <d:getetag /> 
        <c:calendar-data > 
            <c:expand start="20210705T000000Z" end="20210805T000000Z" /> 
        </c:calendar-data> 
    </d:prop> 
    <c:filter> 
        <c:comp-filter name="VCALENDAR" > 
            <c:comp-filter name="VEVENT" > 
                <c:time-range start="20210705T000000Z" end="20210805T000000Z" /> 
            </c:comp-filter> 
        </c:comp-filter> 
    </c:filter> 
</c:calendar-query>
```

The request is made to the url [https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/{calendarID}/events](https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/%7BcalendarID%7D/events)
but the result is not returning single instances of recurring events. Google CalDav Api does support rfc4791 according to https://developers.google.com/calendar/caldav/v2/guide

Comment: Have you tried to get the desired result using the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) version? If you want to get all the elements of a [recurring event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/recurringevents), you have to pass the parameter `singleEvents` = `True`.

Comment: It can be done using the Calendar API but i am trying to use the CalDav API.

Comment: Can you post the response you are receiving for your request?